# Any way to validate XML against XSD file in Apex?

Tags: apex, validation, xml

Im currently using an apex class with Dom.Document to generate an XML file which then gets sent off to an external endpoint.

I would like to be able to validate the XML file against an existing XSD file before sending it off. Is there anyway to do this in salesforce with the DOM.document or any other method, other than writing my own apex code to validate it.

Thank you in advance. I have searched on this site and many other places and haven't came across anything yet.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am looking at something similar..

Comment: Nope, couldn't find a way to do this. Would of been nice but doesn't seem possibly unless you write an entirely custom thing, which would be a lot of work.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to validate XML against a schema in Apex?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/50480/102)

Comment: I have suggested an Idea , you can upvote it .https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CTOkQAO

Answer (score 1):

Trying to validate in Apex would be a mess of a project!  I would probably go with running a pre-built library (like **[javax.xml.validation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html)**) on Heroku, and passing your file off for processing that way.

Comment: Here's a "how-to" :  https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-validate-xml-against-xsd-in-java/